# How can I solve the Android Firebase error "Default FirebaseApp is not initialised in this process"?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using FirebaseAuth for user registration with email and password, and I have already added the plugin and dependencies in my project.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText ed_email, ed_pass;
Button but_login;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=getApplicationContext();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    ed_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_email);
    ed_pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_pass);
    but_login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_login);
    but_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
}
public void registerUser(){
    String email=ed_email.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass=ed_pass.getText().toString().trim();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Input",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Input",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("You are registering...");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }

    });


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    registerUser();
}
```

}

**logcat -**

```
com.skapsdevelopment.firebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.skapsdevelopment.firebase, PID: 31993
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skapsdevelopment.firebase/com.skapsdevelopment.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.skapsdevelopment.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.skapsdevelopment.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.skapsdevelopment.firebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My App is not starting and showing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this 
process com.skapsdevelopment.firebase. 
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Why is the app not starting properly?

Answer (score 22):

Double-check the following as this has worked for me:

Added in your project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

And on your app-build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: When you register an app on Firebase, the steps you mentioned are precisely there as one of the steps required to get your app registered.

So, yes, this is a necessary requirement for working with Firebase.

Answer (score 5):

It's stated in the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) that the FirebaseApp.initializeApp() should be called from the Application.

Did you try to create and Application instance (if you don't have one already), and call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` from its onCreate() method ?

Comment: Yeah... I am doing the same. But still getting the same error. Here's my **onCreate()** Method :

Comment: ` protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        ed_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_email);
        ed_pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_pass);
        but_login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_login);
        but_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    }`

Answer (score 3):

First thing Make sure you register your application in the **Firebase Console** and you have added the **google-services.json** file in the app.

Second Check the whether you have add all the **dependency** or not.
Add following dependency in the **App-bulid Gradle** file:-

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
```

And add in **project level bulid gradle** file:-

```
dependencies
 {
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
 } 
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Dhruvisha --- I couldn't find to add google-services.json for Firebase Auth in the doc

Comment: @Prasad Go to settings - > your apps there you can find a google-service.json file

Answer (score 3):

please add this  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
at the place of  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your app's Project-level `build.gradle` inside dependencies

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`

Then add the following line as the last line in your app's Module-level `build.gradle`

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Now, sync both the `gradle` files and you are good to go.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **initializeApp** in your program. I can show you how it's done.

First create a new class and extend `Application`.

```
public class SimpleBlog extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Lastly, go to Manifest and add in the application like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".SimpleBlog"  <------
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And this is all...

Comment: I am using FirebaseAuth for registration with email & password. Is it necessary to add FirebaseDatabase as you written in onCreate() method above?

Comment: No, FirebaseApp is only for register app, if you can register user can use FirebaseAuth in any class, and use FirebaseAuth.getInstanse() for get user data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers here, I went through the check list of possible issues when I encountered this error.

Finally I realized .. I had started a new module in Android Studio, with a different package name than what's already registered on the Firebase Console for the Firebase instance I had set up.  Simple mistake - I forgot to add the new package name to the Console config.

After I got this right, it started to work.  Remembering all the little details expected by Firebase Console can be tricky sometimes.. gotta be alert/*"config-cognizant"* there for sure

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how did you add the new package name?I have a native android app with unity integrated how do i do that?

Comment: Here's the Firebase setup page https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup . There is a video there, at 2:36 it shows where you can enter a new package name. If you scroll down to section **Step 2: Register your app with Firebase**, there are instructions for adding a new package name.  Here's the equivalent for Unity https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I solved it bro .in my case the issue was never related to firebase so i worked things out by unity plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the above issue. I downloaded all plugins and checked for updates with NuGet. In the end, I found the crashing was due to the *Application Package Name* not matching the one assigned in Google Dev.

- Make sure that your google-services.json is assigned a build action
  of GoogleServicesJson
- Check that your application package name matches the one that you
  assigned in the Google Dev Console

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Remove `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);` as you do not need it in the newer versions of Firebase
2. Add your app with package name to your Firebase project. Download the Google JSON file with your package name and add the downloaded file to your app
3. Add the instructed libraries into both app level and project level gradle
4. Sync the project and you are ready to use Firebase

For further info see the [Firebase Authentication Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case Proguard was causing the problem so this is what I did:
- If there is any class in the AndroidManifest.xml with `"YourClass"` or `".YourClass"`, change it to its full package name: `"com.yourpackage.yourClass"`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade google service plugin from version 4.1.0 to version 4.0.1 in project's build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: Or upgrade to 4.2.0. the version 4.1.0 had a bug that caused this error to occur

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for the party, but I wanted to share my solution. Hopefully it helps others

I had a very similar problem, a few hours ago. Tried everything here, but nothing worked. All my dependencies were correct, which made no sense.

What I didn't know was that this application needed to be registered in Firebase. I followed this step by step [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and *voilà*! It works! Instead of using the recommended classpath dependency, be sure to use this one `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Adding `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` on the activity `onCreate()` method.
2. Downgrading `com.google.gms:google-srvices` in  project level `build.gradle` 
   from 4.2.0 to 4.0.0

that is changing:

```
dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

to:

```
dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every available method from above, but nothing solved this problem entirely. I
did this:

1. Add `firebase_core:` in your `pubspec.yaml`. Add latest version from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)

2. Now, open your main.dart, and then modify your code as follows:

```
   import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

      void main() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
        runApp(MyApp());
   }
```

You just need to call `Firebase.initializeApp()` **once** in your app.