# How to initialize Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.augmentedreality.projectar. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

For the past 48 hours I've been stuck at this Exception, and so far has no clue what's possibly causing this, I've referred all these answers:

- [Default FirebaseApp is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081539/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized)
- [Getting “Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process” despite initializing FirebaseApp while using FirebaseStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763491/getting-default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this-process-despite-initial)
- [FirebaseApp not initializing despite FirebaseApp.initializeApp() being called in Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708272/firebaseapp-not-initializing-despite-firebaseapp-initializeapp-being-called-in)
- [How can I solve the Android Firebase error “Default FirebaseApp is not initialised in this process”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155941/how-can-i-solve-the-android-firebase-error-default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialis)

And yet the problem persists. I am using Firebase Storage as well as Firebase Database. I use Firebase storage to download image using a `Service`. The `Service` is same as the Firebase quick start example from Github[[here]](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/firebasestorage/MyDownloadService.java).

Now, the exception is thrown at this line :

```
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxx.appspot.com/o/Coca-Cola.jpg?alt=media&token=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Based on the answers mentioned in the aforementioned questions, I've made the following changes:

**1)AppMain.java**

```
    public class AppMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        //if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        //    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        //}
    }
}
```

**2) Dependencies**

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
}
```

**Question:** How to fix this issue?

Comment: You could download the entire quickstart application and move your own code into it instead of pulling it apart to work with your own code. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

you dont need them..

use

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

instead,
for full instructions - 
[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Comment: That doesn't make any difference!

Comment: Also remove `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'`. Don't mix Firebase versions 2.x and >=9.

Comment: I would say also update the Firebase version to match the play services

Comment: I switched all dependencies to `10.0.1` , however I am unable to import Jackson classes, do I need a specific dependency now?

Comment: Jackson is no longer included in the Firebase SDK. If you still need it, you can import it explicitly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying this code, 
  You should update the Android studio version. May be your problem will be solved.